# Is it efficient to send all of the views to client in one piece - SPA?

Tags: javascript, meteor, reactjs, single-page-application

Lets say I have 15 different views and all of them are very complicated structured.

I am planning to use meteor and react without server-side rendering. But I can t understand that what if a user is only going to check my home page, in this case isn t it inefficient to send all of the views' html-css-js to client.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right, it is indeed inefficient to send all of your view logic if only some of them are used. You problem boils down to this - Code splitting and chunking. This is where tools like Webpack come in handy.

Using Webpack, you can split your code into bundles, where each bundle will contain logic for a specific part of your application. For example, all code for your login page can be bundled together as `login.bundle.js` and once after login, you can bundle the rest of your view logic as `myapp.bundle.js`.

You can learn more by following the documentation here - http://webpack.github.io/docs/what-is-webpack.html. If you want a guide on how to set it up, here are couple of blogs on how to do this -

https://medium.com/@dtothefp/why-can-t-anyone-write-a-simple-webpack-tutorial-d0b075db35ed#.mdm6p8qkh

https://medium.com/@booleanhunter/webpack-for-the-fast-and-the-furious-bf8d3746adbd#.8aynlj3t4

Code-splitting is only one of the several things that Webpack can do. There are other tools too that can achieve this, like [Browserify](http://browserify.org/)

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

Please look at instruments like `webpack` that have features like `require.ensure` for your case